# Не могу осилить реляционный запрос. Yii

Tags: php, yii, sql

Есть две таблицы - покупатель(t1model) и заказы(t2model).

Сделал такие relation.

```
t1model.relation 
'info'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 't2model', 'idt2', 'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN')

t2model.relation 
'idt2'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 't1model', 'idt2')
```

Делаю такой запрос

```
t1model::model()->with('info')->findAll(array("condition"=>"type=3", "order"=>"name"));
```

Но на выходе получается такой запрос

```
select t1.name, t1.id, t2.data
from t1 inner join t2 on (t1.id=t2.idt2)
where type=3
order by name
```

а должен быть такой

```
select t1.name, t1.id, t2.data
from t1 inner join t2 on (t1.id=t2.idt2)
where t1.type=3
order by t1.name
```

Ни как не могу понять в чём ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Известная проблема. Указывайте в параметрах к какой модели относятся данные

`t1model::model()->with('info')->findAll(array("condition"=>"t1model.type=3", "order"=>"t1model.name"));`

Так же можно написать просто `t1` вместо `t1model`, но кто знает как потом будет называться псевдоним таблицы.

---

UPD: в дополнение советую почитать

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr

Comment: Дело в том, что почему то отладчик ругается на "t1model.type".
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't1model.type' in 'where clause'.
Я поэтому и не понимаю, что тут не так.

Comment: ну в смысле "t1.type"

Comment: так t1 или t1model? =)

если не работает покажите sql

Comment: @Gedweb ну вот что получается

SELECT `t`.`id`, `t`.`name`, `info`.`data`
FROM `t1` `t` INNER JOIN `t2` `info` ON (`t`.`idt2`=`info`.`id`) WHERE (t1.type=3) 
ORDER BY t1.name 

пишу читый запрос 

SELECT `t`.`id`, `t`.`name`, `info`.`data`
FROM `t1` `t` INNER JOIN `t2` `info` ON (`t`.`idt2`=`info`.`id`) WHERE (`t`.`type`=3) 
ORDER BY `t`.`name` 

так всё работает. Тут проблема в алиасах, которые присваивает Yii.

Comment: Работает. Это я забыл как достучаться до данных из другой таблицы.

$row->info->data

Comment: ну так и получилось то, что вы просили в вопросе

 - если условие выборки не по t1model, поменяйте на t2model

 - не нужно обфусцировать до такой степени, называйте таблицы реальными названиями, без цифр

Answer (score 0):

t.type
вообще переименуйте таблицы - они совпадают с алиасами - будет каша!

Comment: findAll - у вас массив на выходе

Comment: t - это уже алиас.
findAll - да, массив на выходе